# How to perf test page with embedded pages (jMeter / angular)

Tags: angularjs, jmeter

I'm trying to do a jMeter test for a page that is using angularjs. The problem is the main page is just a container of sorts that combines several other pages.

Not sure how to explain it, but the source of the page is like this :

```html
<div ng-if="isAuthenticated() && !isTokenRequest">
    <nav id="navBarId" class="row main" ng-include="'App/Views/Shared/navbar.html'" ng-show="showNavbar"></nav>
    <nav id="navSettingsId" class="row main" ng-include="'App/Views/Shared/settingsnavbar.html'" ng-show="showSettingsNavbar"></nav>
    <main id="mainQueryListId" class="row" ng-include="'App/Views/QueryList/QueryList.html'" ng-show="showQueryListTab"></main>
    <main id="mainQueryBuilderId" class="row" ng-include="'App/Views/QueryBuilder/QueryBuilder.html'" ng-show="showQueryBuilderTab"></main>
    <main id="mainDataCardId" class="row" ng-include="'App/Views/DataCard/DataCard.html'" ng-show="showDataCardTab"></main>
    <main id="mainHomeId" class="row" ng-include="'App/Views/Home/Home.html'" ng-show="showTestPageTab"></main>
    <main id="mainBackgroundQueryListId" class="row" ng-include="'App/Views/BackgroundQuery/BackgroundQueryList.html'" ng-show="showBackgroundQueryListTab"></main>
    <main id="mainUsersId" class="row" ng-include="'App/Views/Settings/Users.html'" ng-show="showUsersManagementTab"></main>
    <main id="mainAppSettingsId" class="row" ng-include="'App/Views/Settings/AppSettings.html'" ng-show="showAppSettingsManagementTab"></main>
    <main id="mainAccessDeniedId" class="row" ng-include="'App/Views/Shared/AccessDenied.html'" ng-show="showAccessDenied"></main>
</div>
```

When I run the recorded scenario everything runs like lightning because the only page jMeter validates is the main page, it doesn't load the actual page(s). How can I get jMeter to load everything?

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 3 options:

1. Record all these request using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), replay them, collect and analyze metrics individually
2. Combine requests into a single transaction using [Transaction Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) to see how long does it take to execute alltogether
3. Mimic AJAX behaviour more closely, i.e. one main HTTP Request triggers 10 parallel sub-requests. Unfortunately there are no suitable test elements or plugins, you will have to develop your own imlementation, see [How to Load Test AJAX/XHR Enabled Sites With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-ajaxxhr-enabled-sites-jmeter) guide for more details and few examples

Comment: ad.1) jMeter doesn't seem to record these requests and when I add them manually I don't see anything due to isAuthenticated() and !isTokenRequest (they are on the embedded pages too) failing and returning some base elements without anything loaded; ad.2) no can do due to reason above; ad.3) gonna read that, thx

Comment: ok for use it but how ? where do you place the transaction controller to make it work ? have you ever made work it or it is just supposition?

Comment: my angularJS application is embedded in war and it works normally with jmeter... i will test in nodeJS server